# Remove items from dom and use again later

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is kind of hard to explain, but basically I have an on change event that will filter items in a list based on alt value of an image. It works fine, but I would like to completely remove inactive items from the dom everytime the on change event occurs(or items with the active class).  Can someone explain where I might be going wrong here?

**Note: I have commented out the code that is not needed for the function to work properly.**

Please ignore the active class in the HTML. I have that it there on page load.

```
function projectFilter(){

    $('#filter').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.projects li').each(function(){


//**This section I am unsure about**.
            /*if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                var store = $(this);
                store.appendTo();
            } else{
                $(this).remove();
            }*/


            console.log($(this));
            var alt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
            var split = alt.split(' ');
            var lower = split[0].toLowerCase();
            if(lower == value){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
//**This part just displays a message if no results are found.**
       /*
        var active = $('.projects .active').length;
        if(active > 0){
            $('p.no-results').removeClass('active');
        } else{
            $('p.no-results').addClass('active');
        }
       */
    });
}



<div class="content projects">
        <div class="row long">
            <h1>Projects</h1>
            <div class="p-filter">
                <form class="cf">
                    <select name="filter" id="filter" class="filter right">
                        <option>---</option>
                        <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
                        <option value="education">Education</option>
                        <option value="healthcare">Healthcare</option>
                        <option value="residential">Residential</option>
                        <option value="religious">Religious</option>
                    </select>
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="search">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"> -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col_08">
                <p class="no-results">No results exist. Please choose another selection.</p>
                <ul class="cf">
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Corporate - Saks Fifth Avenue 2" src="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Corporate - Saks Fifth Avenue 3" src="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Corporate - Saks Fifth Avenue 4" src="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/saks_4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia" src="/assets/img/misc/carpentry/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/university_saint_mary_boathouse_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - University of Saint Mary on the Lake Boathouse 1" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/university_saint_mary_boathouse_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/university_saint_mary_boathouse_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - University of Saint Mary on the Lake Boathouse 2" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/university_saint_mary_boathouse_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/century_tower_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Residential - Century Tower" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/century_tower_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/catholic_charities_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Catholic Charities" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/catholic_charities_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/newark_electronics_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Residential - Century Tower" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/newark_electronics_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/holy_family_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Family" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/holy_family_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/saint_mary_lake_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Saint Mary of the Lake 1" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/saint_mary_lake_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/saint_mary_lake_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Saint Mary of the Lake 2" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/saint_mary_lake_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/ss_cyril_methodist_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - SS Cyril Methodist" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/ss_cyril_methodist_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_benedict_bell_tower_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St Benedict Bell Tower" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_benedict_bell_tower_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_james_chapel_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. James Chapel 1" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_james_chapel_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_james_chapel_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. James Chapel 2" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_james_chapel_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_joesph_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Joesph" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_joesph_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 1" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 2" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 3" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_teresa_of_avilia_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_alphonsus_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Alphonsus" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_alphonsus_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_linus_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Linus" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_linus_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_roman_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Roman" src="/assets/img/misc/masonry/st_roman_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ltp_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Corporate - LTP 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ltp_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ltp_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Corporate - LTP 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ltp_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Rectory 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Rectory 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Rectory 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_rectory_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ic_st_joe_school_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - IC St. Joe School 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ic_st_joe_school_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ic_st_joe_school_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - IC St. Joe School 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/ic_st_joe_school_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - St.Giles 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - St.Giles 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - St.Giles 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St.Giles 4" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_5.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St.Giles 5" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_giles_5.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/education_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - Education 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/education_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/education_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Education - Education 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/education_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Cathedral 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Cathedral 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Cathedral 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Cathedral 4" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_cathedral_4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 4" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_5.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 5" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_5.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_6.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 6" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_6.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_7.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 7" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_7.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_8.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 8" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_8.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_9.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - Holy Name Courtyard 9" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/holy_name_courtyard_9.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_julie_billart_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Julie Billart 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_julie_billart_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_julie_billart_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Julie Billart 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_julie_billart_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 4" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_5.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Teresa of Avilia 5" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_teresa_of_avilia_5.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Alphonsus 1" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Alphonsus 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active even"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Alphonsus 3" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_alphonsus_3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li class="active odd"><a href="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_linus_parish_center_2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"><img alt="Religious - St. Linus Parish Center 2" src="/assets/img/misc/contracting/st_linus_parish_center_2.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the li element into variable, and do filteration based on it. See example below :

```
// cache the whole list item into variable
var $li = $('.listItem li');
// register change event
$('#filter').on('change', function() {
   // store search value
   var 
       value = $(this).val(),
       filteredElem;

   // at first, we remove all the list items 
   // completely from page
   $('.listItem').empty();

  // filter out chached element 
  filteredElem = $li.filter(function() {

    var 
        alt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt'),
        split = alt.split(' '),
        lower = split[0].toLowerCase();

    if (lower == value) {
       $(this).addClass('active');
       // take only matched element
       return $(this);
    }

  });

 // append back filtered element into UL
 $('.listItem').append(filteredElem);  

});
```

Noted that i added `.listItem` class on `<ul class="cf listItem">` this element on line `20` in demo page, to easier selecting the output element.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/4s582h3v/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `select` dropdown, and you want to remove the item from the dropdown menu, you can add this below your removeClass code to remove the option completely:

`$(this).remove();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I really want to do is remove the list items that are not active when the option is changed. The code adds and removes the active class right now based on what is selected in the dropdown, but I need to remove those list items entirely until the next time an option is selected.

Comment: if i'm understanding you correcly, then i think you should store your default options in localStorage, or as a global variable, and then you can restore it any time you'd like.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of what you are saying? I sort of get it I think. The part that is confusing me adding active list items when a certain option is selected.

Comment: throw your code into a working example and i'll be happy to make some edits. jsfiddle.net is my personal preference.